# What shield is this item referring to and is it really better than what I have?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-wizard

[image: Picture of the item]

Is this item really better than what I have? Assuming I can enchant this item to have generic damage instead of holy, is it worth the material to do so? Shouldn't the mace be slighly better, especially since it has vitality?

Also, what shield is the set bonus referring to?

Comment: What's wrong with holy damage? And why don't you make a socket instead? An emerald would boost your damage a lot!

Comment: @Novarg I don't do any holy damage with any ability. So on what skill would this applied to in the first place?

Comment: @Assylum The Holy damage is used with the base damage in calculating spell damage. Then, the damage is shifted to whatever element the spell is aligned with. The marker for "Holy Damage" or "Fire Damage" is used to doing additional elemental damage for attacks that don't modify elements such as a normal basic attack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set bonus definitely works with [Galvanizing Ward](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/wizard/passive/galvanizing-ward), but I'm not sure if that's the only spell/passive it works with.

As for which one is better, it depends entirely on what you're going for. Chantodo's Will has more damage *and* has Life on Hit. Neanderthal, on the hand, has Vitality and thorns. If you find yourself taking lots of big hits, then perhaps you want to go with Neanderthal for the life boost. However, if you generally avoid getting hit and only need a bit of recovery in between and during fights, Chantodo's is probably the better choice.

Comment: Diamond Skin should work too.

Answer (score 2):

It will work with every shield that expire after some time. Then refill your life of 25% of the remaining shield amount when they expire.

THAT MEANS IT WON'T WORK ON GALVANIZING WARD (because it never expire unless the shield is entirely used)

But it should work fine with :

- Dominance
- Diamond Skin
- Force weapon - Deflection
- Spectral blades - Barrier blades

It's not an exhaustive list, but I can't think of anything else